# JSON Binary Array to Image in Java

Tags: java, json, c#-4.0

I'm consuming a .NET json service that outputs a byte array. The byte arrary gets converted into the integer representation of each byte. When viewed in Fiddler, it looks like this:

{"imageBackground":[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,...]}

In Java, I've got the data back into a JSONObject, but I'm unfamiliar with Java so I'm not sure where to go from here to convert that into something usable. I suspect if I can get it back into a stream of some sort I should be able to make it viewable as an image (PNG/JPG/etc)...

Any tips form here?

Comment: I'm a little disturbed by the idea that anybody is sending an image that way in the first place. (A JSON string of Base64'ed data would be much better.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `imageBackground` as a byte array, and then hand it off to [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html):

```
byte[] imageBackground = // set me here;
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBackground);
try {
    BufferedImage ImageIO.read(input);
    // do fun stuff with the image...
}
finally {
    input.close();
}
```

I'm not sure what your application wants to do as the image, but once you have a `BufferedImage` you can use `ImageIO` to convert it to another type, you can do transforms, output to a file...the sky's the limit.  You can find a tutorial for that and more by Googling.

Comment: @Andrew Heh heh...I know the feeling.

Comment: Are there any java functions available to facilitate getting the string of integers back into a byte[]?

Comment: certainly...  `String.getBytes()`.  there are two signatures...one which returns in the default character encoding (UTF-16) and another where you can specify the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (the methods names are probably incorrect, don't know them from the top of my head)

```
JSONArray jBytes = theObject.getArray("imageBackground");
byte[] imData = new byte[jBytes.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < jBytes.size(); i++) {
   imData[i] = jBytes.get(i);
}
```

That's how you make it a real byte array. Then do what stevevls posted, or whatever you want.